# Neon equivalent of mm_madd_epi16 and mm_maddubs_epi16

Tags: c, arm, sse, neon

I am trying to port a code in SSE to Neon.

I could not find the equivalent intrinsics for mm_maddubs_epi16 and mm_madd_epi16.

Any insights on these intrinsics for Neon.

Comment: What kind of use-case are you using them for?  As part of a widening horizontal sum?  Or something where both inputs are non-constant, and you actually need widening products as well as one step of adding pairs horizontally?

Comment: My inputs are non constant and i need widening products as well as one step of adding pairs horizontally.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at the implementations is SIMDe for [`_mm_madd_epi16`](https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde/blob/2fdc9a5e5f078cb11107bdd5c79b6a5fa6d8bf43/simde/x86/sse2.h#L3685-L3727) and [`_mm_maddubs_epi16`](https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde/blob/2fdc9a5e5f078cb11107bdd5c79b6a5fa6d8bf43/simde/x86/ssse3.h#L663-L701) (note to future readers: you might want to check the latest version of those files since implementations in SIMDe get improved sometimes and it's very unlikely I'll remember to update this answer).  These implementations are just copied from there.

If you're on AArch64, for `_mm_madd_epi16` you probably want to use an `vmull_s16`+`vget_low_s16` for the low half, a `vmull_high_s16` for the high half, then use `vpaddq_s32` to add them together into a 128-bit result.  Without AArch64 you'll need two `vmull_s16` calls (one with `vget_low_s16` and one with `vget_high_s16`), but since `vpaddq_s32` isn't supported you'll need two `vpadd_s32` calls with a `vcombine_s32`:

```c
#if defined(SIMDE_ARM_NEON_A64V8_NATIVE)
  int32x4_t pl = vmull_s16(vget_low_s16(a_.neon_i16),  vget_low_s16(b_.neon_i16));
  int32x4_t ph = vmull_high_s16(a_.neon_i16, b_.neon_i16);
  r_.neon_s32 = vpaddq_s32(pl, ph);
#elif defined(SIMDE_ARM_NEON_A32V7_NATIVE)
  int32x4_t pl = vmull_s16(vget_low_s16(a_.neon_i16),  vget_low_s16(b_.neon_i16));
  int32x4_t ph = vmull_s16(vget_high_s16(a_.neon_i16), vget_high_s16(b_.neon_i16));
  int32x2_t rl = vpadd_s32(vget_low_s32(pl), vget_high_s32(pl));
  int32x2_t rh = vpadd_s32(vget_low_s32(ph), vget_high_s32(ph));
  r_.neon_i32 = vcombine_s32(rl, rh);
#endif
```

For `_mm_maddubs_epi16` it's a little more complicated, but I don't think an AArch64-specific version will do much good:

```c
/* Zero extend a */
int16x8_t a_odd = vreinterpretq_s16_u16(vshrq_n_u16(a_.neon_u16, 8));
int16x8_t a_even = vreinterpretq_s16_u16(vbicq_u16(a_.neon_u16, vdupq_n_u16(0xff00)));

/* Sign extend by shifting left then shifting right. */
int16x8_t b_even = vshrq_n_s16(vshlq_n_s16(b_.neon_i16, 8), 8);
int16x8_t b_odd = vshrq_n_s16(b_.neon_i16, 8);

/* multiply */
int16x8_t prod1 = vmulq_s16(a_even, b_even);
int16x8_t prod2 = vmulq_s16(a_odd, b_odd);

/* saturated add */
r_.neon_i16 = vqaddq_s16(prod1, prod2);
```

Comment: Eliminate the `vdupq_n_u16(0xff00)` by trading `vmulq_s16` for `vqdmulhq_s16`